# Should Multiple Instances of an Android Activity show up in Memory Analyzer?

Tags: android, memory-leaks, android-activity

When I click through my application navigation I find that Android is creating a new instance of the activity each time I launch the new Intent (using the following code):

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Based on what I've read this seems to be the default behavior.  I would have guessed this means that the heap will now have multiple instances allocated to maintain the application's history.  However Patrick Dubroy says in his [video on Memory management](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk&feature=player_detailpage#t=2185s) that only one instance of an activity should show up in your heap dump unless there's a memory leak.

My question is two-fold:  Am I correct that a new activity instance is created each time the intent is launched? If so, does having multiple instances appearing in the heap dump indicate that there is a memory leak?

**Update**
Based on [the Tasks and Back Stack guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html):

> Because the activities in the back stack are never rearranged, if your application allows users to start a particular activity from more than one activity, a new instance of that activity is created and pushed onto the stack (rather than bringing any previous instance of the activity to the top). As such, one activity in your application might be instantiated multiple times (even from different tasks)

Comment: You have a leak, you are probably holding on to a reference which itself references the activity context, e.g. bitmaps that you're create in the activity and are holding a reference to somewhere else.   If you do something like this, you leak the entire activity.  Android will not create 2 instances of your activity.

Comment: When you say "Android will not create 2 instances of your activity" what do you really mean by that?  Because the only way it would be a memory leak is if Android was creating another instance (otherwise there would be no issue with holding onto the reference).  Is what you're really saying is that my first instance should have been destroyed?

Comment: I just tested with a brand new application.  No references, no bitmaps, nothing on the activity other than the "Hello world" text. After switching back and forth between two blank activities several times the heap dump is showing multiple objects for each activity which is very confusing for me based on what Patrick's video says.

Comment: Are you sure that you are not looking at dereferenced instances waiting for garbage collection?  Think about it.  Imagine if Android did create multiple instances of Activities.  There would be chaos and low memory constantly.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, which is why this behavior confused me as well. But this appears to be the default behavior if I don't set the flags that David referred to below.

Comment: Having read David's answer, I now understand the question, I think!  Are you talking about multiple activities, not multiple instances of the same activity?

Comment: I'm actually referring to multiple instances of the same activity. I've edited my question to include a reference to the documentation that confirms that multiple instances will be created and added to the stack (which is the behavior I'm seeing).  So based on that documentation it looks like the statement Patrick made in the video is not 100% accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If, in your application, you are doing this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

then, indeed, Android will create a a new instance of `HomeActivity` and put it on top of the activity stack. This will result in **multiple instances** of `HomeActivity`. If that isn't what you want (and it probably isn't what you want), then there are several possible ways of dealing with this.

Since I don't know your application and you haven't posted any code or anything, I need to make some assumptions. I'm going to assume that your `HomeActivity` is the first activity that you use to start your application (otherwise known as the **root activity**). I'm also going to assume that `HomeActivity` starts other activities and **does not** call `finish()` on itself when launching other activities.

If this is the case, then you can return to your `HomeActivity` from any activity in your application by doing this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

Assuming that `HomeActivity` is **not** defined with `android:launchMode="singleTop"` in the manifest, this will cause all activities in the activity stack (including `HomeActivity`) to be finished and will create a new instance of `HomeActivity` as the only activity in the stack.

If you would like to just remove all activities **except** the existing instance of `HomeActivity` and just return to that instance, you need to do this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, HomeActivity.class);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
startActivity(intent);
```

This will cause all activities in the activity stack (**except**`HomeActivity`) to be finished and will call `onNewIntent()` and then call `onResume()` on your existing instance of `HomeActivity`.

If my assumptions are incorrect, please correct me and I can suggest other things.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. Would you say it's generally considered a good idea to add these flags to any intent unless you have an explicit reason not to?

Comment: Definitely not! You can use specific Intent flags to achieve specific behaviour. In your case, you want to return to an existing activity that you know is in the activity stack and you want to remove any unfinished activities that may be present. But in most cases this isn't necessary. You should only set Intent flags when you want to alter the default, standard behaviour and this shouldn't be necessary that often.

Comment: I see.  This is actually clearing the back history which is not really the desired behavior.  My navigation doesn't exist on a home screen so I don't want to return the user to the home screen every time.  So, it seems the answer to my question is yes, a new instance will be created each time I launch an activity.  And that instance will be added to the history stack.